# How to save attachments?

Tags: c#, mimekit

I am using MailKit/MimeKit 1.2.7 (latest NuGet version).

I have been reading the API documentation and several posts on stackoverflow. But I still wasn't able to successfully save email attachments as a file.

Here is my current code:

```
var mimePart = (attachment as MimePart);
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
mimePart.ContentObject.DecodeTo(attachmentStream);

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
      memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

I have been trying this code with different kinds of attachments. The created file on my disc is always empty.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the above code is that you are forgetting to reset the `memoryStream.Position` back to `0` :-)

However, a better way of doing what you want to do is this:

```
var mimePart = (attachment as MimePart);

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    mimePart.ContentObject.DecodeTo(fileStream);
}
```

In other words, there's no need to use a temporary memory stream.

Comment: And this is the third and final question you helped me with today. And it's working perfectly too. I can't thank you enough for your help (and MailKit/MimeKit), Jeffrey. I got everything working now :) Have a nice day!!